# How can I pick specific string fragments out of an excel cell using a custom formula written in VBA

Tags: string, delimiter

At work I am required to reformat incorrect Addresses on a weekly basis from records in our Salesforce instance. We gather the incorrectly formatted addresses using a Report and export them to an Excel file. My job is simply to manipulate the data in the file to format them properly then reinsert them into the database.

Typically the addresses are formatted as so:

**5 Sesame Street, Anytown, Anyplace**

Separating these can be done easily by hand, but I typically have to work with hundreds of addresses at a time, and using default excel formulas tends to require lots of wrangling multiple cells at once to break it up into fragments.

Thus I wrote a custom formula to run through the cell and return a specific fragment of the string based on the "Comma Number" given. So if I give a Comma Number of 1, I would get "5 Sesame Street", 2 would get me "Anytown", etc.

Here is my code so far:

```html
Public Function fragmentAddress(address As String, numberofcommas As Integer) As String
seen = 1
lastComma = -1
Dim x As Long
Dim frag As Long

For x = 0 To Len(address)
    If Mid(address, x, 1) = "," & numberofcommas = seen Then
        Exit For
    ElseIf Mid(address, x, 1) = "," & numberofcommas <> seen Then
        seen = seen + 1
        lastComma = x
    End If
Next
frag = Mid(address, lastComma + 1, seen - lastComma)
fragmentAddress = frag
```

I have not implemented the ability to handle the final value yet, but it does not give me any outputs, only outputting a "#VALUE!" error when I attempt to give it the input

```html
=fragmentAddress("3 Ashley Close, Charlton Kings",1)
```

I have some experience with programming, but this is my first time writing anything in VBA.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what your question is, but this is simpler:

```
Public Function GetAddressFragment(ByVal Address As String, ByVal Index As Integer) As String
    Dim addr() As String

    addr = Split(Address, ",")

    On Error Resume Next
    GetAddressFragment = Trim(addr(Index - 1))
End Function
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you
Apologies for the question being convoluted